# Manipulating the output of a file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am trying to manipulate the output of this file so it prints each line on a new line rather than this:

> ['antelope\n', 'bear\n', 'cat\n', 'dog\n', 'elephant\n', 'fox\n',
>   'giraffe\n', 'hyena\n', 'iguana\n', 'jaguar\n', 'kangaroo\n',
>   'llama\n', 'monkey\n', 'ninja turtle\n', 'octopus\n', 'platterpus\n',
>   'queen bee\n', 'rat\n', 'snake\n', 'tiger\n', 'unicorn\n', 'vole\n',
>   'whale\n', 'yak\n', 'zebra']

```
myFile=open('animals.txt', 'r')
animalList=myFile.readlines()
print(animalList)
```

Answer (score 0):

use of `context manager` `with` statement will be good.

```
with open('animals.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       print(line, end='')
```

you don't need `file.readlines()` here because file object itself calls its `next()` method.

Comment: Note that the context manager `with` has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks i didn't consider for python3, check i update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `join` string method:

```
animalList = open('animals.txt', 'r').readlines()
print("".join(animalList))
```

Note that the `join` method is part of the empty string here: `"".join(` *some list of strings* `)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
     myFile=open('animals.txt', 'r')
     animalList=myFile.readlines()
     for animal in animalList: 
           print(animal)
```

Comment: Please fix your typo's.